# How to pass int[] as argument between plpython functions

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, plpython

I'm working with PostgreSQL and plpython functions.

I have a function `func1`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(a integer, b timestamp with time zone, c integer[])
  RETURNS SETOF x AS
$BODY$

parts=plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM func2(%s)"%c)

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
```

`func1` calls `func2` with the c argument which is `integer[]`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(v_c integer[])
RETURNS SETOF y AS
$BODY$
    .
    .
    .
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
```

when running it from SQL query

```
select *
from func1(3,'14-Feb-2012','{-2,30747,30906}')
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  spiexceptions.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM func2([-2, 30747, 30906])
```

something with passing the `intger[]` isn't working i also tried :

```
plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM func2(%s)"%str(c))
```

it doesn't work as well.

Comment: `print` the SQL sentence to see how to fix; `strip('[]')`

Comment: print what? it shows that it calls `SELECT * FROM func2([-2, 30747, 30906])` this is how it suppose to be. func2 with int[] i don't know why it says error.

Comment: forgive me. I didn't notice you use plpy. I wonder if you can insert `func()` which a function into your `SELECT` sentence

Comment: if I lose the `[]` it looks for a signature func2(int,int,...int)

Comment: I think you should format the `SELECT` sentence with the result returned by `func2()`. SQL would do `eval('func(...)')` inside.

Comment: But `func2` fails on call... before it returns anything. the `int[]` doesn't not pass so `func2` can't operate.

Answer (score 1):

Probe this:

```
create or replace function func1(t text[]) returns integer as $$
    p = plpy.prepare("select func2($1) v", ["text[]",])
    r = plpy.execute(p, [t,]) 
    return r[0]["v"]
$$ language 'plpythonu';

create or replace function func2(t text[]) returns integer as $$
    return len(t)
$$ language 'plpythonu';

select func1('{"a", "b"}'::text[]);
> 2
```

I think the best way is pass the list (postgres array) as parameter in the execute. It is necessary to prepare statement first.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if you solved this, the problem is plpy will not automatically format python to sql types, what I would do is format the call to func2:

Instead of:

```
parts = plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM func2(%s)"%c)
```

Try:

```
c = [-2, 30747, 30906]
c = '{' + ','.join(str(i) for i in c) + '}'
q = "SELECT * FROM func2('{}')".format(c)
plpy.notice(q)
parts = plpy.execute(q)
```